# Детектирование спам-писем, при помощи нечеткого хеширования

Tags: спам

Есть задача, **детектировать спам-письма при помощи нечетких хешей**. На данный момент я сделал упор только на содержание самого сообщения, без заголовков, отправителей и т.д.

И столкнулся с проблемой, что информации в интернете, на эту тему практически нет. Нашел кучу примеров с машинным обучением, примеры, где используется расстояние Левенштейна и т.д., но по теме нечетких хешей информации я практически не нашел. Пытался даже подобраться к этой теме, через детектирование вредоносного ПО и сигнатурный анализ, но понял, что это не то, что нужно.

Мой вопрос, заключается в следующем, как реализовать детектирование спам писем используя нечеткие хеши?

Подскажите пожалуйста, алгоритм решения простыми словами, поделитесь ссылками на какие-нибудь источники, в которых желательно есть, хотя бы пример псевдокода. В общем и целом, что-нибудь, что поможет мне реализовать то, что требуется.

Comment: Краткое гугление вывело меня на следующее ключевое слово: `ssdeep_fuzzy_hash`, код там в основном для `PHP`, но есть и `Python`, например. Сам алгоритм я не очень понял, но вроде бы там используется скользящее окно как-то.

Comment: Ещё вот `MinHash`: http://ekzhu.com/datasketch/minhash.html

Comment: Но я бы всё-таки советовал двигаться в сторону машинного обучения, если вы действительно хотите решать эту задачу, а не просто до нечётких хешэй докопаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf это да, есть такое. Но куда хеш полученный от этой функции можно отдать, или что с ним сделать, чтобы новое сообщение например определить как спам? Эти хеши можно сравнивать, и пока идея только, что-то придумать с кластеризацией. И мне именно нужны нечеткие хеши((

Comment: Дальше там у первой библиотеки вроде расстояние Левенштейна меряется между хэшами, а у второй Жаккарда. Получается, нужно либо иметь образцы спама и со всеми ними расстояние мерить, ну либо да, лучше тогда кластеризацию. Но что мешает кластеризовать нормально преобразованные по канонам `NLP` тексты, почему именно нечёткий хэш? Есть стандартный довольно процесс, описанный в множестве мест, пользуйтесь. Если в рамках машинного обучения, то это просто классификация спам/не спам, я думаю есть 100500 руководств в интернете по этой теме.

Comment: @CrazyElf 1) посмотрел видео, как раз на тему детектирования спам писем при помощи нечеткого хеша, и в нем все так же, используется алгоритм CTPH для хеширования, для сравнения расстояние Левенштейна, и так же алгоритм кластеризации DBSCAN, вот сейчас пытаюсь понять, что мне нужно передать в DBSCAN. 2) Как я написал в самом вопросе, да я нашел кучу вариантов решения, но вот мне нужно именно нечеткий хеш, курсовая работа скажем так.

Comment: Если реализация DBSCAN от sklearn, то там можно передать параметр metric='jaccard', а Левенштейна готового там нет вроде, но там можно и прямо функцию свою передавать в metric. Разницы особой думаю не будет, Жаккард тоже пойдёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf как я выяснил, в dbscan на обучение, нужно передавать матрицу дистанций. Собственно, передал, обучил, но видимо из-за того, что матрица дистанций практически вся забита нулями одними, результат адекватный от новых значений, получить не удалось. Результат dbscan был один шум.